# I am using ExistsAsync to check whether the CloudBlockBlob is exists but it is taking too much time

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

```
foreach(var lst in list)
{
    CloudBlobDirectory dira = container.GetDirectoryReference(folderName + "/" + prefix);
    bool isExists = dira.GetBlockBlobReference(filename + ".png").ExistsAsync().Result;
    
    if(isExists)
    {
        // create sas url using cloud block url 
    }
}
```

I am using this code to check if blob exists for each path But ExistsAsync() is taking too much time.
I have also tried GetBlobClient in loop but it was also taking time.
Is there any other way to check if blockblob is exists
I am using the latest version(12) of Azure.Storage.Blobs

Comment: How long does it take? How fast do you want it to go? How big is that list? One way to make it faster would be to actually use ```async``` ```await``` and chunk up your list (you should avoid using ```.Result``` in general). Execute a chunk of them at the same time and await them with ```Task.WhenAll```. If you still don´t manage to get it fast enough for your needs you´ll need to use a faster datastore  / database and store your blob paths in that. So you have a faster datasource to query against. Azure Blob isn´t great at querying data.

Comment: What you are doing does not make much sence though as ```lst``` is never used. You also are not using ```Azure.Storage.Blobs``` as far as I can tell because ```CloudBlobDirectory``` is not a class in that library, it´s part of ```Windows.Azure.Storage```.

Answer (score 0):

It´s not entierly clear what OP wants to do. One naive way to try and make Blob queries faster is to execute multiple in parallel.

Note that this example actually uses `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, while op seems to be using `Windows.Azure.Storage` despite stating otherwise.

```cs
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;

var blobClient = new BlobServiceClient("<connection string>");
var container = blobClient.GetBlobContainerClient("<container name>");

// However your list looks like, Im assuming it´s partial or full paths in blob
var potentialBlobs = new List<string>() { "<some>/<blob>/<path>" };

// Amount to execute in parallel at a time, depends on your system which value will yield better results.
// Could be calculated based on Environment.ProcessorCount too (note that this can return 0 or negative values sometimes, so you have to check)
const int chunkSize = 4;
var existingBlobs = new List<string>(); 

foreach (var chunk in potentialBlobs.Chunk(chunkSize))
{
    // Create multiple tasks
    var tasks = chunk.Select(async path => // potentialBlobs list item
    {
        var exists = await container
            .GetBlockBlobClient(path) // adjust path however needed, I don´t understand what OP wants here
            .ExistsAsync();
        return exists ? path : null;
    });

    // Wait for tasks to finish
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    // Append to result list
    foreach (var cur in results)
    {
        if (cur is not null)
            existingBlobs.Add(cur);
    }
}
```

There does not seem to be an Exists method available in the `BatchClient` of `Azure.Storage.Blobs.Batch`. As far as Im aware of it´s only mostly for adding, updating or deleting blobs not to check for their existence. So I think it is not viable for this scenario, but I might have missed something.

---

If you cannot get acceptable performance this way you´ll have to store blob paths in something like table storage or cosmosdb that is faster to query against. Depending on what you need you might also be able to cache the result or store the result somewhere and continuously update it as new blobs get added.

Comment: Actually I have a foreach loop of a datatable which contains the blob path and in that loop I am checking if the blob exists and if it is need to create sasurl

Comment: Your initial post does not use ```lst``` at all. So it does the same thing over and over again. So, with the code provided your exists check could even be outside the loop and it would do the same (Im just assuming that is not the point of this). You either coded it wrong or left out all the parts that would be needed to make any sence of the code part.

Comment: bool blob = this.container.GetBlobClient(path).Exists();
                    if(blob)
                    {
                        BlobClient blob1 = this.container.GetBlobClient(path);
                        var URI = blob1.GenerateSasUri(Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.All, DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(180));
                        string url = URI.ToString();
                         dr[columnName] = url;
                    }                                                                                                         this code is in loop but taking time

Comment: Exists is taking too much time Is there anything else which I can do

Comment: Parallelizing the loop, as shown in my answer would be easiest as it does not require maintaining another datastore and should still give a good speed up. Otherwise, make sure you can tell if a blob exists without asking azure blob storage if it exists by keeping queryable **up to date** metadata records to your blobs in a more performant database with the blob path and additional data that answer your queries. So you can lookup blobs there efficiently and only talk to blob when reading or writing data to it.